# Stack Overflow inbox bug

Tags: support, reputation, notifications

I earn reputation every day on Stack Overflow. Recently, I have been seeing that the inbox doesn't show any notifications. But when I click on the inbox, I see a lot of comments on my question. Why doesn't the inbox notify me? Is this a bug? Several people comment on my questions by calling me but the inbox doesn't notify me. The same is the issue with Recent Achievements. It doesn't notify too when I earn or lose rep.

Comment: Which site does this happen on? Which browser are you using? Have you tried hard-reloading the page by using `Ctrl`+`F5`? Are there errors in the console (`F12`) indicating that some JS or WebSocket connection failed to load or got blocked? No repro here.

Comment: It happens on StackOverFlow. I am using Chrome. I have tried everything you stated but no solution

Comment: Plus there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only notified when your reputation exceeds a previous high water mark. Usually people notice this [when they've placed bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209467/ignore-the-rep-change-caused-by-placing-bounties-in-the-achievements-reputation).

Looking at [your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16516173/el-primo?tab=reputation) however, you had a voting reversal event on August 23. Your reputation will need to exceed 255 before you'll get new notifications.

Comment: I haven't placed any bounties.

Comment: This answer might be true for the recent achievements/reputation gain notification issue but isn't related to the inbox/comment notification issue.

Comment: I must admit, those 2 sets of voting reversals looks like some sock puppeting.

Comment: Yes @Larnu A random user tried to upvote all my questions. The mods detected me and banned me for 7 days.

Comment: It was not even my mistake!

Comment: That's why a voting reversal was called on my account -140 rep for 14 questions and answers in total